# How to add python-kivy support to my arm-board booting with yocto linux images

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, yocto, kivy-language

I have downloaded [python-kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git) from git hub. Now I want to add this python kivy to my yocto `(krogoth-2.1.2)` source. Still I don't know how to compile this `python-kivy`. Please help me how to compile the kivy and test in board.

1. Is there any dependencies for kivy.

Board: AM335x based board. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a whole documentation on installation and dependencies on the github link you provide: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/kivy/latest/kivy.pdf

Comment: how can i add support to yocto for my embedded device. is any body written yocto recipe for kivy. Please provide i am new to yocto Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking someone to write a recipe for you? That's fine but not really appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dear @jku, what i meant was , I thought may be it is present in any git repo or i need to write? Thanks!!! Now i understard there is no recipe i will try my self. Thanks again.

Comment: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/ -- great resource for finding recipes in various layers. Undortunately no hits for kivy.

Comment: @rao, could you provide the solution you implemented? Having the same problem. How did you solve dependecy problems? I'm trying to install Kivy version 1.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way is to [create a layer](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-your-own-layer) and write a python-kivy recipe file for it.

Writing a recipe for a python package is very easy. The one you mention is even [hosted as well in pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kivy/1.10.0) which makes it even easier:

Take this as the [simpliest example](https://github.com/urnenfeld/meta-widde/blob/master/recipes-devtools/python/python3-typing_3.5.2.2.bb):

> inherit pypi

Inheriting this class, yocto is guessing the package name and version from the file name, and basically you just need to place the checksums.

Note that this provides the *python3* version of the component, you need to inherit from *setuptools* instead of *setuptools3* if you want the *python2* version

In the same github link there are other recipes which solves some other minor issues which you can encounter when writting this kind of recipes.